# Xcode Workspace, using Cocoa Pods fails to build on other machines

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, restkit, cocoapods

I'm trying to get an Xcode workspace running on another developer's local machine, before adding it all into source control.

The workspace was generated by Cocoa Pods when adding RestKit to a project, and it all works fine on my machine (and from any location on my Mac where I copy the  directory containing the workspace to), but after copying the same directory onto another machine, including all the project code and Pods directory, it fails to build.

There are multiple errors listed, starting with a `parse issue` in the `Restkit.h` alias file in `\Pods\Headers\Build\RestKit\RestKit`. The file it points to exists on both machines, so I'm guessing this (and the many other errors that are listed) are misleading, and this issue is down to some sort of Header Search Path / linker issue?

Has anyone got any ideas what could be causing the workspace to fail to build on a second machine? Any tips on where to start looking would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you copy it to another machine and what do you then do?

Comment: Just a simple file copy, and the then open the workspace created by Cocoa pods in Xcode, and it then fails to build. I'm guessing it's got to be some sort of environmental difference between the machines, or an absolute path somewhere in the workspace / project, but I've not been able to spot anything when searching through those files in a text editor.

Comment: generally you should commit then checkout and pods install on the other machine

Comment: It's a long story, but I have done, and will be doing that again in the future, but we've had this problem building the workspace created on my machine on others, hence leaving source control out of it for now, just to attempt to get it to build on a second machine.

Comment: so the same version of pods is installed on both machines, you clean the project after copying it, pod install and build?

Comment: The project has been cleaned more times than I can remember now! We wanted to avoid having to run pod install etc, on every machine, so the Pods directory is included in all the code we've copied over from my machine. As far as I understand Cocoa Pods, this should be possible shouldn't it?

Comment: BTW - thanks for the interest Wain, I realise this 'What is the reason behind this project not building? (And no, I've not got any useful error messages)' is a bit on the impossible / thankless side...

Comment: Just to go back to basics, are you sure you're opening the .xcworkspace on the second machine, not the .xcodeproj? And you're attempting to build/run the entire project? I have seen Xcode default to a different target, like a specific cocoapod, the first time it opens a workspace.